# What are the best ways to learn to distinguish vowels?

Tags: vowels, language-acquisition, perception

Apologies if this question is redundant. It seems pretty basic, but I couldn't find a post that seemed relevant. If there is one, please forward it!

My question is "What are the most effective ways to learn to distinguish different vowels?"

This question is prompted primarily by my own desire to improve EFL learners' listening ability, but it applies more generally to language learning, including my own. I should explain the learners' context a little more. They can generally produce the correct phones when speaking in isolated, targeted exercises, but tend to revert to allophones in their native* language in actual speech segments. On the listening end, they have trouble distinguishing the vowels even in isolated words and sometimes in minimal pairs.

A common example is /i/ and /ɪ/. In the speakers' native language they use both, but /ɪ/ is considered an allophone of /i/. This particular case is probably common across many languages but some students even have trouble distinguishing the /æ/ and /ə/ sounds which to me seem much more distinct.

Sorry if I am being a little verbose, but I think this is a highly relevant topic for language learners and linguists. ^_^

*I should note that for many speakers what I am calling their "native" language is actually their L2 as this learner community is comprised of students who come from communities where a local dialect is their actual L1.

Comment: This question would better fit at [languagelearning.se]

Comment: You may find some suggestions in J.C. Catford's _A Practical Introduction to Phonetics_, which was designed for autodidacts to learn to use their inbuilt phonetics lab.